# How to FlatMap a Publisher of two Tuples into a Publisher with one Tuple

Tags: ios, tuples, combine, publisher

I have the following code

```
 private var codeState : AnyPublisher<((Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool),(Bool,Bool)), Never> {
    let publ1 =  Publishers.CombineLatest4(firstCodeAnyPublisher,secondCodeAnyPublisher,thirdCodeAnyPublisher,fourthCodeAnyPublisher)
    let pub2 = Publishers.CombineLatest(fifthCodeAnyPublisher, sixthCodeAnyPublisher)
    return publ1.combineLatest(pub2)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

This operation produces any publisher with two boolean tuple
How can I convert them to a publisher with one tuple the following

```
AnyPublisher<(Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool), Never>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel compelled to say that publishing a tuple of two unnamed `Bool`s or four unnamed `Bool`s or six unnamed `Bool`s is probably a bad idea. You should at least label the values, and probably you should create `struct`s instead of using tuples.

That said, you can apply [the `map` operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/map(_:)-99evh) to merge the tuples:

```
private var codeState : AnyPublisher<(Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool), Never> {
    let publ1 =  Publishers.CombineLatest4(firstCodeAnyPublisher,secondCodeAnyPublisher,thirdCodeAnyPublisher,fourthCodeAnyPublisher)
    let pub2 = Publishers.CombineLatest(fifthCodeAnyPublisher, sixthCodeAnyPublisher)
    return publ1.combineLatest(pub2)
        .map { ($0.0, $0.1, $0.2, $0.3, $1.0, $1.1) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

In fact, [`combineLatest` has an overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/combinelatest(_:_:)-1n30g) that takes the transform function as an extra argument and applies `map` for you, so can also write it this way:

```
private var codeState : AnyPublisher<(Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool), Never> {
    let publ1 =  Publishers.CombineLatest4(firstCodeAnyPublisher,secondCodeAnyPublisher,thirdCodeAnyPublisher,fourthCodeAnyPublisher)
    let pub2 = Publishers.CombineLatest(fifthCodeAnyPublisher, sixthCodeAnyPublisher)
    return publ1.combineLatest(pub2) {
        ($0.0, $0.1, $0.2, $0.3, $1.0, $1.1)
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

You should use whichever version you find easier to understand. Neither one is more efficient than the other.